# explanations regarding reading files from os by python

Tags: python, file, directory, operating-system

i am reading files inside a folder by using this :

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))]
```

it returns a collection of file names in string format in a list collection. like `['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']`

the issue is whenever i extract files from zip to a folder it messes up with sequence of elements inside list so it gives ['1.png', '3.png', '2.png'] like that
and whenever i give a path to a different folder where i would place images by downloading each image one by one from chrome it retains its sequence.
i just don't know why it happens.

i tried changing sort by in in windows view option itself to different sorting like date created , date changed , sizes, dimensions but nothing worked

i just want explanation why it messes up with sequence ,i got the temp. sol thought ,
right now im soring the list inside python script itself by natsort but still I want explanation.

Comment: There is nothing to "mess up" with sequencing as the files are not inherently ordered in the directory. If you need them ordered it a particular way just sort to ensure it and move on.

Answer (score 0):

os.listdir retrieves the files in order of the index given by the file system. So downloading the files 1 by one keeps them in order as the file systems indexes them in order. So the order of the files depend on what order your archiving software decides to unarchive the files.